# How to restrict branch deletion access in gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite

Currently my gitolite.conf has configuration in such a way that branches can be deleted by the authorized users

```
repo testing
    RW+    =    @test_rw
    R      =    @test_r
```

I want the to restrict the users from deleting master and Development branch. Only feature branches could be deleted by the users

How can this be achieved with gitolite.

Answer (score 0):

You could [use a VREF](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html), and in that VREF script, disallow any deletion on certain branches.

```
repo testing
    RW+                  =    @test_rw
    R                    =    @test_r
    -   VREF/NODELETION  =   @all
```

With `NODELETION` a script [similar to this one](https://08178170481999681358.googlegroups.com/attach/8f7b29851f748f10/TRASH.txt?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrH1tmX6XRps8aj2JB8Dtgirx6Rk1oLemm_-R-ojYMcZPtaUk0ExfPIWhpR5p5BfHQ8gYCjTOG1LOElmkAAHGHV8nA65zf_1MEEYywwh3c6XQfL-MFQ), in that it would include a test like:

```
if [[ "$ref" =~ ^refs/heads/master ]]
then
    die "Not allowed to delete master."
fi
```

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gitolite/%2420branch%2420deletion/gitolite/nytDWM5AbUw/EI90H4Upe48J) has other examples of VREF scripts based on branches.